# Cannot go fullscreen by dragging a app in mission control

Tags: macos, mojave

Steps I'm doing:

1. 4 Fingers up to open Mission Control
2. Dragging any app to the top (e.g. Finder)
3. Nothing is happening it is not going full screen.

Did I do something wrong on settings and never noticed? I cycled through many boots it seems like a permanent thing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by enabling `Displays have seperate spaces` in System Preferences (Found under Mission Control). Then logout and log back in to apply the setting.

[image: Image of the Setting]

Comment: It’s helpful if you put instruction on how to get to those settings an/or adding a screen capture of the window with the settings.